# The redirect URI in the request: did not match a registered redirect URI

Tags: redirect

I am creating a web application which includes a login through google account. Till now, everything was fine but when a user logs in, the page is not redirecting correctly.  It shows me the error message as

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost/gamifield/after_login.php did not match a registered redirect URI

Learn more
Request Details

cookie_policy_enforce=false
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
response_type=code
redirect_uri=http://localhost/gamifield/after_login.php
access_type=offline
display=page
prompt=consent
client_id=911903894752.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

Although I have given correct and same redirect URI in both google console and in my code.

Comment: Ah, you "expect someone to solve your problem soon"? Good to know. What will happen if we do _not_ obey?

Comment: As I am new to stackoverflow, the only thing I required is the solution,that's it!

Comment: Thanks for removing that strange closing :-)